# É recomendável usar PHP caching? Como usar?

Tags: php, cache

*PHP caching* é basicamente um cache criado do seu site para evitar que se gaste processamento buscando dados a cada requisição de página. Quando um usuário acessa uma página, é salva uma cópia da mesma em HTML no servidor, essa cópia é válida em um determinado tempo, após esse tempo é chamada a página original e criada uma nova cópia.

Na teoria, a aplicação dessa prática torna o site mais rápido, pesquisei sobre o assunto e encontrei alguns exemplos, segue o que mais me agradou:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];
$cachefile = 'cached-'.substr_replace($file ,"",-4).'.html';
$cachetime = 18000;


if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
    include($cachefile);
    exit;
}
ob_start();
```

O código acima é responsável por verificar se já cache daquela página, caso exista então é chamado ele, caso não exista, o *script* continua sendo rodado tenho seu conteúdo padrão.

```
<?php
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush();
```

Já nesse código, é criado e aberto o arquivo de cache e chamado ao navegador.

É recomendável usar este método?

Em vários casos teremos uma área de *login*, e cada usuário terá acesso à partes diferentes, ao salvar esse cache o usuário não acabaria pegando dados do outro(exibindo a página de cache do outro)?

Se sim, como evitar?

E como usar corretamente essa técnica (caso a que coloquei aqui esteja errada)?

Comment: Caso a página possa ser acessada por todos os usuários e é a mesma página sem modificações acredito que poderia usar CDN como o CloudFlare ou Incapsula (este último promete um melhor desempenho nesse casos) ou pode usar o Sucuri. São soluções pagas, mas que não são tão caras (o CloudFlare possui um plano gratuito, mas não sei se oferece este recurso), nas alternativas pagas temos o Sucuri por ~10 dólares, o CloudFlare por ~20 dólares e o Incapsula por ~40 dólares, salvo engano. É só uma sugestão além da pergunta! Dados dinâmicos (comentários) podem ser carregados por JS. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro: recomendável onde? Em um site com poucos acessos ou com milhões de acessos?

Cache é vantajoso quando há muito acesso em certos padrões. Ele não é algo mágico que se coloca e o site fica rapidão. Ele pode até dar um ganho, mas não ser uma vantagem real. Em alguns casos o site pode ficar mais lento. Este site aqui que está usando agora (ums dos 30 mais acessados do mundo) tinha um monte de cache, um dia resolveram desligar alguns deles e ficou mais rápido.

"Pra variar" a resposta é que tem que medir (o SO usava sem medir e acreditava ter ganho quando tinha perda). Tem que fazer e simular o padrão de acesso para ver se ocorre um ganho significativo. Precisa identificar gargalos e saber onde o cache precisa atuar. Se não houver gargalos, o cache é irrelevante.

Cache traz malefícios. Se a informação necessita ser precisa não pode usar cache. A não ser que o cache possa ser determinado pela produção de conteúdo e não por tempo determinado. Sempre que é viável eu prefiro essa forma, afinal o cache pode sobreviver mais tempo se nada mudou e é invalidado assim que for necessário. Mas isso gera um custo tão grande que acaba não compensando na maioria dos casos.

Cache para conteúdo de apenas um usuário tem pouca ou nenhuma vantagem. Aí precisa ver se precisa dessa pequena vantagem ou não. Um ganho pequeno multiplicado por milhões de pessoas é algo significativo, para meia dúzia é esforço demais para ganho quase zero. Depende do padrão de uso da aplicação.

Se o cache for bem-feito não pegará dados de outro usuário. Se for ingênuo, pegará. Aí mostra que não precisava de cache. A solução básica para evitar isso é gravar um identificador do usuário no nome do arquivo e indicar que só ele pode acessar aquele cache.

Até há ganho em cache em arquivo, mas não é nem de perto de algo que só exista na memória. Pode ocorrer o contrário em alguns casos.

Esse código pode ter uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) que pode apenas não ajudar tanto, ou causar problema. Pode ser que não tenha problema hoje, mas pode ter um dia.

Pela pergunta não dá para saber se haverá problema adicional. Não dá para entender o fluxo todo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).