# Quando usar o MemoryCache?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, cache

Gostaria de um exemplo real, não necessariamente de código, sobre **quando** utilizar o `MemoryCache` em sistemas Web. Que tipos de situação pedem por seu uso?

Um pouco de contexto: participei de uma entrevista em que me fizeram essa pergunta e eu não soube responder, pois nunca fiz nenhum tipo de *caching*. Nos sistemas em que já dei manutenção praticamente todas as consultas eram feitas diretamente no banco de dados. Embora o volume de informações fosse grande, nunca tivemos problemas com performance, e o que tínhamos era resolvido com índices ou outras soluções diretamente no banco, mas nunca na aplicação em si.

Comment: bom dia,
geralmente em aplicações onde retornam uma grande massa de dados de informações de conta de acesso do usuário onde não tem a precisão de ir no banco a todo momento estar buscando informação do usuário, podemos estar usando um MemoryCache para estar guardando os dados na aplicação

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pergunta é um pouco ampla, mas vamos lá.

Imagino que já leu a [documentação dele](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Pelo menos é isso que o programador faz quando vê algo novo que não conhece e deseja saber mais. Não vou falar o que já está lá, não parece ser o foco.

Cache é uma das estratégias mais importantes e mais usadas para fazer dados serem acessados mais rapidamente. Cache é mais simples do que as pessoas imaginam. Você fazer um cálculo e guardar em uma variável está fazendo cache. Quer mais simples que isso? Claro, aqui estamos falando de um mecanismo um pouco mais sofisticado.

Cache é extremamente complicado conforme vai saindo do trivial, principalmente quando precisa [decidir sobre invalidação dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356320/101). Mas cache é apenas uma forma de entregar uma informação de um jeito mais rápido que a forma tradicional, não importa muito como. Um exemplo seria a [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104014/101) que é o padrão de projeto básico usado em grande parte dos mecanismos de cache.

Você pode ter vários níveis de cache na aplicação e no entorno dela. Pode ter algo que faz parte da sua aplicação ou que é feito por terceiros em infraestrutura que você usa direta ou indiretamente, algo de hardware ou software. Saber escolher quais usar e quais são exagero é uma arte. Alguns você não escolhe, existe e boa. Como é muito complicado fazer certos caches é melhor usar algum mecanismo pronto em boa parte dos casos.

Então a pergunta é mais embaixo, é quando usar o cache. Quando ele for necessário então o `MemoryCache` deve ser sua escolha (mas pode ter outros níveis de cache fora da sua aplicação). Ele será correto, tem a forma que provavelmente é mais eficiente, controles de concorrência e principalmente já [deve ter uma ou mais estratégias de invalidação que funcionam razoavelmente bem na maioria das situações](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E uma das coisas mais importantes é ter um [monitoramento para invalidar sob demanda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.changemonitor?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), que é uma das invalidações mais consistentes que existe (com vantagens e desvantagens).

O exemplo real depende da situação, por isso é muito difícil colocar um exemplo. De qualquer forma não importa o mecanismo, importa entender todo o processo de desenvolvimento de software para absorver sobre a necessidade de cache. Não tem uma resposta mágica, a não ser que deve usar quando precisar de mais performance e um teste mostrar que o cache resolve parcial ou totalmente. Não existe nenhuma situação que dá para dizer que deve usar sempre ou deve usar nunca, inclusive porque o mesmíssimo problema pode mudar se o volume mudar.

Existem problemas que o cache ajuda pouco ou nada ou atrapalha. Se você tem acesso raro ao mesmo dado o cache é só um estorvo. Somente o padrão de repetição do acesso aos mesmos dados várias vezes é que te dá vantagem clara.

Já [respondi sobre para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139932/101), continua válido aqui.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).